# Azure Web App - Howto update MinTlsVersion using the fluent API

Tags: c#, azure, web, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to update the **MinTlsVersion** setting of a Azure Web App using the Fluent Management API:

```
app.Inner.SiteConfig.MinTlsVersion = SupportedTlsVersions.OneFullStopZero;
```

However, the **SiteConfig** property is always NULL, and I am not able to find a way to load it.

I am able to update other settings like **HttpsOnly**, but not the ones below the **SiteConfig** property.

```
app.Inner.HttpsOnly = true;
```

Does anyone know how to change the **MinTlsVersion** using the Fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no MinTlsVersion property in Azure fluent API. You could refer to Azure SDK to check [SiteConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.models.siteconfig?view=azure-dotnet) class.

Also, if you want to set up MinTlsVersion for Azure web app, you could use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration) to achieve it.

**Prerequisites**:

Setting up a Tenant ID, Client ID, and Client Secret for Azure Resource Manager provisioning. You could refer to this [article](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/cloudlifecyclemanagement/46/setting-up-a-tenant-id-client-id-and-client-secret-for-azure-resource-manager-provisioning-669202145.html) to get some parameters you will need.

Then you could refer to the working code as below:

```
var appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://management.azure.com/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + @"subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxxxxxx/config/web?api-version=2016-08-01";
    string body = "{\"properties\": {\"minTlsVersion\":\"1.0\"}";
    var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PutAsync(requestURl, stringContent).Result;
}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: I am referring to the following API [link]https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net I do have a MinTlsProperty there?

Comment: The following namespace: Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models.SiteConfig

Comment: I have check the link you provided, and it also contain [MinTlsVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.models.siteconfig?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet-preview) property. Sorry for my mistake to give you a error link. I have update my reply you could refer to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the **MinTlsVersion** with the following code.

```
SiteConfigResourceInner siteConfig = new SiteConfigResourceInner();                
siteConfig.MinTlsVersion = SupportedTlsVersions.OneFullStopZero;         
await azure.WebApps.Inner.CreateOrUpdateConfigurationAsync(resourceGroup, app.Name, siteConfig);
```

Still not able to get/load the current value though.